# How to say "should_receive" more times in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this in my test

```
Project.should_receive(:find).with(@project).and_return(@project)
```

but when object receive that method call two times, I have to do

```
Project.should_receive(:find).with(@project).and_return(@project)
Project.should_receive(:find).with(@project).and_return(@project)
```

Is there any way how to say something like

```
Project.should_receive(:find).with(@project).and_return(@project).times(2)
```

Answer (score 232, accepted):

## This is outdated. Please check [Uri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25744654/1644614) below

for 2 times:

```
Project.should_receive(:find).twice.with(@project).and_return(@project)
```

for exactly n times:

```
Project.should_receive(:find).exactly(n).times.with(@project).and_return(@project)
```

for at least n times:

```
Project.should_receive(:msg).at_least(n).times.with(@project).and_return(@project)
```

more details at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/receive-counts under **Receive Counts**

Comment: Seems like maybe this doesn't work with `any_instance`?

Comment: @YoLudke I don't know

Comment: Should use the new syntax mentioned in [Uri's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25744654/1747491).

Answer (score 92):

The new `expect` syntax of rspec will look like this:

for 2 times:

```
expect(Project).to receive(:find).twice.with(@project).and_return(@project)
```

for exactly n times:

```
expect(Project).to receive(:find).exactly(n).times.with(@project).and_return(@project)
```

for at least n times:

```
expect(Project).to receive(:msg).at_least(n).times.with(@project).and_return(@project)
```

Comment: The `have_received` syntax also works. `expect(Project).to have_received(:find).exactly(n).times` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`should_receive`, as opposed to `any_instance`, expects that the class receives message the specified number of times.

`any_instance` on the other hand is generally used for stubbing a method.

So the first case is an expectation that we would like to test, while the second one is getting past a method to the next line so we can move on.

Comment: Drenmi I appreciate the time you have taken to add a few comma's to a post I had added almost a year ago... It did not look like there was any change to the technical aspect of the answer... Why would you down vote me for this...?

Answer (score 0):

@JaredBeck pointed out. The solution didn't work for me on `any_instance` call.

For any instance i ended up using stub instead of should_receive.

```
Project.any_instance.stub(:some_method).and_return("value")
```

This will work for any no. of times though.

**Update:** Syntax is deprecated. See comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595203/rspec-any-instance-deprecation-how-to-fix-it