# RSpec: how to test if a method was called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When writing RSpec tests, I find myself writing a lot of code that looks like this in order to ensure that a method was called during the execution of a test (for the sake of argument, let's just say I can't really interrogate the state of the object after the call because the operation the method performs is not easy to see the effect of).

```
describe "#foo"
  it "should call 'bar' with appropriate arguments" do
    called_bar = false
    subject.stub(:bar).with("an argument I want") { called_bar = true }
    subject.foo
    expect(called_bar).to be_true
  end
end
```

What I want to know is: Is there a nicer syntax available than this? Am I missing some funky RSpec awesomeness that would reduce the above code down to a few lines? `should_receive` sounds like it should do this but reading further it sounds like that's not exactly what it does.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328277/how-to-say-should-receive-more-times-in-rspec

Comment: @Peter Alfvin The OP was asking for syntax on `should_receive`, so I thought that question would help.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

```
it "should call 'bar' with appropriate arguments" do
  expect(subject).to receive(:bar).with("an argument I want")
  subject.foo
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding how this format of "to .. receive(:bar)" checks for the value of "called_bar" in this example.  Can you explain that to me?

Comment: @ecoding5 no. It doesn't and neither should check for `called_bar`. That was just a flag to ensure that the method was called, but with `expect(...).to receive(...)` you are already covering that. It's more clear and semantic

Comment: @wacko oooh, got it, thanks for the clearing that up. I didn't catch it the first time.

Answer (score 112):

In the new `rspec` [`expect` syntax](http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/) this would be:

```
expect(subject).to receive(:bar).with("an argument I want")
```

Answer (score 45):

The below should work

```
describe "#foo"
  it "should call 'bar' with appropriate arguments" do
     subject.stub(:bar)
     subject.foo
     expect(subject).to have_received(:bar).with("Invalid number of arguments")
  end
end
```

Documentation: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#expecting-arguments

Comment: Thank you - I was receiving "NoMethodError" has_received? - think this might be to do with rspec versoins though. I found another solution that worked for me (the one marked correct above)

Comment: @MikeyHogarth This answer was suggesting `have_received` (the after the fact "spies" approach), not `has_received`, which is not part of any version of RSpec that I know.

Answer (score 4):

To fully comply with RSpec ~> 3.1 syntax and `rubocop-rspec`'s default option for rule `RSpec/MessageSpies`, here's what you can do with `spy`:

> Message expectations put an example's expectation at the start, before you've invoked the
>   code-under-test. Many developers prefer using an arrange-act-assert (or given-when-then)
>   pattern for structuring tests. Spies are an alternate type of test double that support this
>   pattern by allowing you to expect that a message has been received after the fact, using
>   have_received.

```
# arrange.
invitation = spy('invitation')

# act.
invitation.deliver("foo@example.com")

# assert.
expect(invitation).to have_received(:deliver).with("foo@example.com")
```

If you don't use rubocop-rspec or using non-default option. You may, of course, use RSpec 3 default with expect.

```
dbl = double("Some Collaborator")
expect(dbl).to receive(:foo).with("foo@example.com")
```

- Official Documentation: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies
- rubocop-rspec: https://docs.rubocop.org/projects/rspec/en/latest/cops_rspec/#rspecmessagespies