# Expect to receive always succeeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

There are several cases, where my specs always *return* true, making the test superfluous...

Take this `Achievement` model for instance:

```
class Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stages

  def call_name_method
    name
  end

  def name
    key
  end
end

# for simplicity sake, I'm just testing a method which simply calls another method.
```

**achievement_specs.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Achievement do
  describe '#call_name_method' do
    subject { achievement.call_name_method }
    let(:achievement) { create(:achievement) }

    it 'calls #name' do
      expect(achievement).to receive(:name)
      subject
    end
  end
end
```

This test succeeds, *but* I can change it to `expect(achievement).to receive(:foobar)` and it will still succeed, although I am not calling `foobar`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22603620/2235594), it is the correct syntax, but it somehow never fails. Is this a bug?

I also tried using `.to have_received(:call_name_method)`, but that results in this error:

> 1) Achievement#call_name_method calls #name
>        Failure/Error: expect(achievement).to have_received(:call_name_method)
>          # expected to have received call_name_method, but that object is not a spy or method has not been stubbed.

Comment: achievement.stages is a relation; also Stage does not have a method `register!`. What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test if the `register!` method of Achievement calls the `register!` method on its stages, and I added the Stage model with its method

Comment: what is achievement in subject { achievement.call_name_method } ? Do you need to override the achievement in the next line?

Comment: achievement is a factory, which does get defined the line after yes. I could also switch the lines, that does not make a difference

Comment: The code looks fine. The error must be elsewhere. If you provided a minimal example that we could run, that'd be perfect.

Comment: Hmm maybe you are right... I'll try and reproduce it on a fresh app...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the **rails_helper.rb**

```
config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean

  RSpec::Mocks.teardown # <-- this line was fault
end
```

After removing that line the specs worked as expected. A coworker accidentally commited this although it was not needed.

Since all test were 'succeeding', it did not catch our attention until now.