# How to test if method is called in RSpec but do not override the return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

There are already [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262309/rspec-test-to-see-if-a-method-was-called) similar to this, but they all override the return values to `nil` unless `.and_return` is called as  well

**PROBLEM**

I am wondering if there is a way to just check if a method is called using `expect_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:somemethod)` and it runs normally without overriding or affecting the return value of `.somemethod`.

- rspec-3.4.0
- rails 4.2

Consider the following:

```
# rspec
it 'gets associated user' do
  expect_any_instance_of(Post).to receive(:get_associated_user)
  Manager.run_processes
end

# manager.rb
class Manager
  def self.run_processes
    associated_user = Category.first.posts.first.get_associated_user
    associated_user.destroy!
  end
end
```

The spec above although will work because `:get_associated_user` is called in the `run_processes`, however it raises `NoMethodError: undefined method 'destroy!' for NilClass` precisely because I mocked the `:get_associated_user` for any instance of Post.

I could add a `.and_return` method like `expect_any_instance_of(Post).to receive(:get_associated_user).and_return(User.first)` so that it will work without raising that error, but that already is a mocked  return value (which might affect the rest of the  code below it), and not the correct expected value it should have returned at the time the method is called.

I can however specify `.and_return(correct_user)`  where `correct_user` is the user that is going to be the same return value as if it has ran normally. However, this will need me to mock every return value in the sequence `Category.first.posts.first.get_associated_user` just so that it will work normally. The actual problem is a lot more complex than above, therefore stubbing is not really a possible solution in my case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> You can use `and_call_original` on the fluent interface to "pass
>   through" the received message to the original method.
>
> https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method

```
expect_any_instance_of(Post).to receive(:get_associated_user).and_call_original
```

However the use of `expect_any_instance_of` might be telling you that you have a code smell and you should be testing the behavior - not the implementation.

```
# test what it does - not how it does it.
it 'destroys the associated user' do
  expect { Manager.run_processes }.to change(Category.first.posts.first.users, :count).by(-1)
end
```

Comment: I've been looking for this for months! :) How could I miss that. Thanks a lot!  You are right that `expect_any_instance_of` is not always gonna be accurate and specific to the test because precisely of the word `any instance`. I just have a specific case where I want to test the "implementation" rather than the "behavior" because it is manipulating an image, and I cannot think of a way to correctly test that the image has been updated as expected. Therefore, I just tested that the method is called, and pray that it worked :)

Comment: Don't you need to actually call the method after the `expect`? Like `Post.new.get_associated_user()`.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei no, not when you call expect with a block. RSpec runs `Manager.run_processes` (the block) once it reaches the last matcher.