# How do you check the return value of a method called inside another method rspec?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec3

Let's say you have some class like

```rb
class Foo
  ...
  public def methodA
    x = methodB(true)
    # other operations (assume x is not the return value of methodA)
  end

  private def methodB(arg)
    if arg
      return 1
    else
      return 0
    end
  end
end
```

When you're writing a unit test for `methodA`, you want to check that `x` was assigned the right value, which means you have to check that the call to `methodB` returned `1` like you expected.

How would you test that in rspec?

Right now I have (with help from [How to test if method is called in RSpec but do not override the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455670/how-to-test-if-method-is-called-in-rspec-but-do-not-override-the-return-value))

```rb
@foo = Foo.new
expect(@foo).to receive(:methodB).with(true).and_call_original
```

But I don't know how to verify the actual return value of `methodB`.

Comment: I would argue that you cannot test `methodA` properly in the given example. Because even if you test that `method_b` returns an expected value, you still didn't test that `x` had that value assigned. And furthermore, these are all implementation details. What if `x` gets renamed? What if `methodB` gets refactored? Your tests should not care about the internals of methods or private methods. Instead, test the response of the entire `methodA` or its side-effects.

Comment: `methodA` doesn't return anything meaningful. It's what happens inside it that I want to verify. FWIW idrc that it's "assigned" to `x`, I just want to make sure that throughout the course of `methodA`, when `methodB` is inevitably called, it returns what I expect - also wrt side-effects, `x` is locally scoped, so there is no other way for me to check it, like you might with a class attribute or something

Comment: @notacorn : The situation you describe basically is about `methodB` returning a certain result for a givin argument. Whether you call `methodB` with this particular argument from inside `methodA`  or from a different place, should hopefully make no difference. Hence I would simply write a separate test case involving `methodB` only.

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of mocking you can just call the private method?

```
@foo = Foo.new
result = foo.send(:methodB, true)
expect(result).to eq 1
```

This is basically testing the private method directly. Some people frown upon doing that but if it has lots of logic it's sometimes easier to test it directly. I agree with @spickermann that it's usually best to test the public method and leave the implementation details of the private methods out of the specs.

Comment: since this is a unit test for `methodA`, I don't want to directly invoke `methodB`, only `methodA`. I'm really just asking if it's possible to check that return value.

Comment: Where is the difference between testing `methodB` directly and calling `methodA` but only to check what `methodB` returned to `methodA`?

Answer (score 0):

### Don't Test Multiple Methods in a Single Unit Test

You're going about this wrong, because you're creating an unnecessary dependency between two different methods. Instead, you should refactor your code so that:

1. *x* is an argument to #methodA,
2. *x*, *@x*, or *@@x* is a variable accessible to methodA that you can set to whatever expected value you want, or
3. stub out #methodB for this unit test.

As an example of the last:

```rb
describe Foo do
  describe 'methodA' do
    it 'does something when methodB returns 1' do
      # stub the default subject, which is Foo.new
      allow(subject).to receive(:methodB) { 1 }
      expect(subject.methodA).to eq('foo bar baz')
    end
  end
end
```

This code is untested, because your posted code is not a complete, verifiable example. While you'd really be better off refactoring your code so you aren't testing nested depedencies at all, using [test doubles or method stubs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs) are certainly viable options.

Comment: so you're saying the class Foo is written incorrectly? `methodB` is a helper method to extrapolate some of the variable interpolation so I don't really see why using a private helper to assign a local variable is "wrong" - I don't see how you refactor that, as the arguments for `methodB` which I excluded from this example, are determined variably in `methodA` as a precursor

Comment: so basically what I'm saying is that (1) and (2) don't really seem like viable solutions, maybe (3) is the only answer. I'm still curious if what I am asking for (originally, anyway) is possible in rspec

Comment: @notacorn What I'm saying is that you didn't post a minimal, complete, verifiable example. Based on what you *did* post, you're testing more than one method at a time. Don't do that. The problem you're having is a common one when people don't write their tests before writing the implementation.

Comment: How is `Foo` not a minimal complete verifiable example? I simply excluded the `initialize` method with the `...`, otherwise it would be a completely valid ruby class.

Comment: @notacorn  "it would be a completely valid ruby class" - it is. It also doesn't make sense to test this implementation, because _nothing happens in it_. That assignment to `x` that you want to test, it doesn't matter if it happens or not, because x is not used.

Comment: The assumption is that x is used later. It makes no sense to make up a use case for it, given that I'm supposed to provide a **minimally** reproducible example. It literally doesn't matter, if you understand the intention/context. If you really wanted, I could replace everything with `puts` statements, but the point stands.

Comment: @notacorn: ah, but this is the whole point, you see. If it was used in a `puts`, you could check that the desired side-effect happened (certain content was sent to stdout). That's what me and the others are trying to tell you: test the behaviour, not the implementation details.

Comment: I think this is a point of frustration that a lot of people have for SO. Questions are asked about how to do X and none of the answers directly answer X but pivot to Y and Z. I am happy to admit that maybe I don't even need to make an assertion on the return value of `methodB`, but that doesn't answer the original question of how you would do it anyway.

Comment: @notacorn: it's answered in the other question, though: test that method directly. I don't think rspec have facilities for `expect(obj).to receive(:msg).with(true).and_also_it_should_return(1)`. This drive-by testing is not done. At least, not in my experience.

Comment: right, I was moreso looking for an answer that would be more upfront about not so much what I should do, but in this case like you're alluding to, whether it even *can* be done