# How to spy on a method called at class level on ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

If I have a model

```
module MyModule
  def bar(str)
    puts str
  end
end

MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule
  bar('foo')
end
```

My spec:

```
describe MyModel do
  before do
    described_class.stubs(:bar)
  end

  it 'calls bar with correct arguments' do
    # This does not work because it is called before it gets stubbed
    expect(described_class).to have_received(:bar).with('foo')
  end
end
```

How can I spy on `MyModule#bar` when called from `MyModel`?

Using rspec-rails 2.99 and mocha 0.13.3

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code doesn't make sense. Is `MyModule` a class, or a module? Currently it's a class *and* a module, and it includes itself??! Where is the `bar` method defined? What does your test look like?

Comment: How have you tried to set up the spy currently? What result do you expect? What result do you get? If there's an error, what does it say?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [`RSpec: how to test if a method was called?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262309/rspec-how-to-test-if-a-method-was-called)

Comment: `MyModule` is a module with a method `bar`. `bar` gets called by `MyModel` which includes `MyModule`. Maybe you misread the names?  The issue as you may know is ActiveRecord models are defined and consequently call `bar` before Rspec even begins running.

Comment: @TomLord I added more details

Answer (score 2):

If you call elsewhere MyModel.new.bar, you can write in the test

```
expect_any_instance_of(MyModel).to receive(:bar)
```

If you want to use 'spy', you can use:

```
allow_any_instance_of(MyModel).to receive(:bar)
```

If you have link to your MyModel instance inside the test, you can rewrite above examples such way:

```
expect(my_model_instance).to receive(:bar)
```

or

```
allow(my_model_instance).to receive(:bar)
```

You should understand that after including any module into you class, instance of that class will be receiver of the method.