# RSpec any_instance deprecation: how to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

In my Rails project I'm using rspec-mocks using any_instance but I want to avoid this deprecation message:

`Using any_instance from rspec-mocks' old :should syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new :expect syntax or explicitly enable :should instead.`

Here is my specs:

```
describe (".create") do
  it 'should return error when...' do
    User.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
    post :create, user: {name: "foo", surname: "bar"}, format: :json
    expect(response.status).to eq(422)
  end
end
```

Here is my controller:

```
def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end
```

I'd like to use the **new :expect syntax** but I can't find how to use it properly.

I'm using RSpec **3.0.2**.

Comment: what is your Rspec version ?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use [`allow_any_instance_of`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ExampleMethods%3aallow_any_instance_of):

```
describe (".create") do
  it 'returns error when...' do
    allow_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
    post :create, user: {name: "foo", surname: "bar"}, format: :json
    expect(response.status).to eq(422)
  end
end
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: And now the `allow_any_instance_of` is also [marked as deprecated](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/old-syntax/any-instance). Any other solution?

Comment: @AlexisWilke - from what I understand - it is now considered a design smell - you are expected to design your service in such a way that you don't need to stub "any instance", but strive to stub specific instances instead...

Answer (score 8):

I am able to reproduce it :

In my test.rb file :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Foo
  def baz
    11
  end
end
```

In my test_spec.rb file

```
require_relative "../test.rb"

describe Foo do
  it "invokes #baz" do
    Foo.any_instance.stub(:baz).and_return(20)
    expect(subject.baz).to eq(20)
  end
end
```

Now If I run it :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec
.

Deprecation Warnings:

Using `any_instance` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead. Called from /home/arup/Ruby/spec/test_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'.
```

Now, I found the [*changelog*](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/Changelog.md#300beta1--2013-11-07)

> `allow(Klass.any_instance)` and `expect(Klass.any_instance)` now print a **warning**. This is usually a **mistake**, and users usually want `allow_any_instance_of` or `expect_any_instance_of` instead. (*Sam Phippen*)

I change `test_spec.rb` as below :

```
require_relative "../test.rb"

describe Foo do
  it "invokes #baz" do
    expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:baz).and_return(20)
    expect(subject.baz).to eq(20)
  end
end
```

and it works perfectly :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec
.

Finished in 0.01652 seconds (files took 0.74285 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby>
```