# Rspec how to expect to receive a message "with", when object receives message twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following example:

```
it 'receives message' do
  expect(Foo).to receive(:bar).with(baz)
  OtherClass.send(baz)
end

class OtherClass
  def self.send(baz)
    Foo.bar(1) # this first one is the problem
    Foo.bar(baz)
  end
end

class Foo
  def self.bar(whatever)
    puts whatever + " was received"
  end
end
```

This is the error:

```
Failure/Error: Foo received :bar with unexpected arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.relishapp.com%2Frspec%2Frspec-mocks%2Fv%2F2-13%2Fdocs%2Fmessage-expectations%2Freceive-counts&ei=DJWjVJrFI4OTuASe64DICQ&usg=AFQjCNHWJiMpH07zxktW21Lvu6v5pk--6Q&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E

[How to say "should_receive" more times in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328277/how-to-say-should-receive-more-times-in-rspec)

Also you can use like "expect(Foo).to receive(:bar).twice".