# Counting the number of times a method is called without stubbing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

It is possible to count the number of times a method is called using [RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328277/how-to-say-should-receive-more-times-in-rspec). However this technique stubs out the method requiring you to provide a return value (otherwise it'll return `nil`). Is it possible to count the number of times a method is called *without* stubbing it? I still want the method to run and return the value it normally should.

Comment: RSpec provides [and_call_original](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation) for calling the original implementation

Comment: @SampatBadhe This looks like exactly what I'm asking for. Thanks!